# How to get result from 2 table and dont show duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables

```
USERS
------------
id   | user
1    | john
2    | George
3    | Andy

Text
--------------------------------
id | user |date        |text
1  |  1   |2012/10/2   | ABC
2  |  3   |2012/11/2   | ABCD
3  |  2   |2012/12/2   | ABCDE
4  |  2   |2012/1/2    | ABCDE
```

In the `Text` table the `user` column gets the `id` from the `Users` table.

I have the following query:

```
   $sql= mysql_query ("SELECT
    user.id,
    users.user,
    CASE
        WHEN text.date = CURDATE() THEN '1'
        ELSE '0'
    END AS 'today',
    text.date,
    text.text
FROM  users user, text text
WHERE users.id = text.user;");

if (mysql_num_rows($sql)<=0)
echo  "NO ENTRIES FOUND";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{

          $user =$row['user'];  
           $id  =$row['id'];  
             $date2  =$row['date'];  

            if ($row['today'] == 1) { echo"
 <div class='z'><a href='viewuser.php?id=$user'>$user</a></div><br>         
        "; } else { echo"
 <div class='zx'><a href='viewuser.php?id=$user'>$user</a></div><br>         
        "; }; 

}
```

My question is:

How can I display the users whose date is equal with today's date, the first `div(zx)`, and if not with the second `div(z)`, comparing from 2 tables and display once if is it 2 times the user.

Comment: but what if a user has multiple dates, one that matches and one that doesn't match?

Comment: Do you want to display users with 'zx' class who wrote text today? Or something else?

Comment: Yes  and for the one didn't class=z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->

SELECT
    u.id,
    u.user,
    CASE
        WHEN t.date = CURDATE() THEN '1'
        ELSE '0'
    END AS 'today',
    t.date,
    t.text
FROM  users u, text t
WHERE u.id = t.user;
```

Now to display the results just say

```
if ($row['today'] == 0) { class="zx"; } else { class="z"; }
```

Code is abbreviated, let me know if you need it detailed out.

Here is your updated code with my solution from above:

```
$sql = mysql_query ("
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.user,
    CASE
        WHEN MAX(t.date) = CURDATE() THEN '1'
        ELSE '0'
    END AS 'today'
FROM  users u, text t
WHERE u.id = t.user
GROUP BY u.id, u.user");

if (mysql_num_rows($sql) <= 0)
    echo  "NO ENTRIES FOUND";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $user =$row['user'];
    $id =$row['id']; 


if ($row['today'] == 1) {
     echo "<div class='zx'><a href='viewuser.php?id=$id'>$user</a></div><br>";
} else {
     echo "<div class='z'><a href='viewuser.php?id=$id'>$user</a></div><br>";
}

}
```

Comment: I just recreated your 2 tables exactly and this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks how i will display it?

Comment: while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
           
          $user =$row['user'];  
     $id  =$row['id'];  
       $date2  =$row['date'];  
   
   
 echo"
 <div class='zx'><a href='viewuser.php?id=$user'>$user</a></div><br>         
        ";
}

Comment: I need to edit this to return both dates for you, hold on, I thought you only wanted the earliest date returned.

Comment: There you go @user1421432. Basically just say if ($row['today'] == 1) { class="zx"; } else { class="x"; }; Code is abbreviated, let me know if you need it all written out.

Comment: if is possible put it together to get the idea

Comment: i have putten it as you typed it and gives the error of: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in .

Comment: @user1421432 please see the update to my answer and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: is working good, now i understood what you did! nice.. and the final think was to be once and not twice the user.

Comment: Sorry, it should be $row['today'] == 1, not $row['today'] == 0. I will change the code. Please also make sure to check this answer as being the answer to your question.

Comment: i will , hot to stop the duplicity of the user when is more than once in the text table